# HTML5 Video tag always downloads full video in Safari

Tags: html, mobile, safari, amazon-s3, html5-video

I have the following HTML5 video tag:

```
<video id="vid"  controls="controls" preload="metadata">
    <source src="/testvid.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

As soon as the video is clicked, Safari begins downloading the entire video file and does not stop until it gets to the end. The video file is 400 MB, so this is a problem due to the cost of the bandwidth.

It does not seem to be a problem with the location of the index in the file, as the app at http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/ says the index is already at the start, and the start of the video is playable immediately even though the rest is still being downloaded.

The source file is in Amazon S3, and so the server supports range requests.

Is there anything I can do? Ideally I would like some sort of sensible buffer, e.g. 20 MB of content ahead of the playhead, or 1 minute, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal behaviour is that a small portion of the video is downloaded when the page loads (just enough for the browser to display a frame and to get the file headers). When you play the video, the whole video is downloaded while it plays.

In some older versions of browsers, the video downloads again if you use the seek bar.

There is no setting or attribute you can use to change this behaviour.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140710090010/https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201106/Blog/HTML-5-Video-In-Real-Life/)

Comment: In that case the HTML5 video tag seems fairly broken to me, it means if you have a page with several videos, and a user is looking at the first few seconds of a few of them, then they will all be downloaded in full!

Comment: I think the problem you have is intent. Some users pause playback to allow the video to download when they have a slow connection - rather than have it keep pausing because it plays faster than it downloads. If you stopped downloading because playback was paused, they would have a poor experience.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sohnee. To lower your bandwith you have two options:

compress your video to a lower quality, or what's your videosize/bitrate ( f.e. h264 with 427x240 800kbps i end up with approx. 5-6mb/min)

think about a playlist (guess southpark.de is doing it like that), cut your movies into several parts and if video is on end, load next one into player. disadvantage: if you use custom controls, they only show infos of current video and not the whole (could be solved if you build your custom controls with special magic).

don't know if it helps, but this would be my two solutions in this case. best K